# В каком формате хранить подгружаемый контент в SPA

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, spa

Есть сайт интернет-журнала состоящий из главной страницы и набора статей - сейчас всё это отдельные статичные страницы типа index.html, article1.html, article2.html и т.д. Но появилось желание оформить это всё в виде приложения (SPA), что бы был один шаблон и просто загружать в него тело статьи.

**Вопрос**: *в каком виде тогда хранить текст статей на сервере?* Т.е. достаточно много текста с разметкой.

Мне приходит в голову решение с использованием:

```
<link rel="import" href="/folder/article1.html">
```

Тогда, соответственно, текст статьи я буду хранить в виде готовой разметки, но может кто-то знает более элегантное решение?
Например, можно ли в каком-то виде для этого использовать json и как тогда быть с разметкой?

Comment: Больше всего возможностей для оформления будет при хранении html, если наворотов больших не нужно, возможно markdown подойдет. Ну и в простом случае json, где, например отдельно заголовок, отдельно текст.

Comment: Зачем здесь SPA? Возьмите любой генератор статических сайтов и не стреляйте из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Ну или вордпресс, у него админка удобная.)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд нехорошо смешивать разметку и сам текст.

Я бы отдельно держал например, `html` наблон(ы) в которые, в свою очередь подгружаются данные, которые сваливаются с сервера в виде `json`. Как их хранить данные на сервере - на мой взгляд - не очень важно, можете генерировать эти json "на лету", а можете и в готовом виде хранить, как вам удобнее